# Strange behaviour from ltrim() with forward slash

Tags: php

I need to remove the beginning part of a URL:

```
$test = "price/edit.php";
echo ltrim($test,'price/');
```

shows `dit.php`

Here is a codepad if you want to fiddle: https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/DominantCalmingBerlinPrice

Any ideas what is going on? I want it to echo `edit.php` of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ltrim` removes ALL characters found, consider the following:

```
$test = 'price/edit.php';
echo ltrim($test, 'dprice/'); // outputs t.php
```

For this particular scenario, you should probably be using `str_replace`.

Comment: Unfortunately str_replace isn't going to work as I intended....what happens if I have the following $test = "test/price/edit.php".  It will remove price from the middle where I only want to remove it the string begins with it.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `ltrim()` is a character mask (a list of characters) that should be removed. `e` is a character that should be removed and so it is removed from `edit`.

There are many string manipulations that you could use, however since this is a filename/filepath the correct tool is a Filesystem Function, [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
echo basename($test);
```

For more information on the filepath check into [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I didn't get that it was a character mask.

Comment: Unfortunately basename will not work. I want to support any url length (for example price/sample/edit.php would produce sample/edit.php) and if it encounters test/price/edit.php it would not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have faced the same problem some time ago and found this solution use it if it suits your need

```
   <?php

    $test = "price/edit.php";
    echo ltrim(ltrim($test,'price'),'/');

output 

edit.php
```

but i must say you should use `basename` as all type problem

```
 <?php

    $test = "project/price/edit.php";
   // echo ltrim(ltrim($test,'price'),'/');// this will give oject/price/edit.phpedit.php

    echo basename($test); // and it will generate edit.php
```

Comment: Unfortunately I want to support any urls (for example price/sample/edit.php produce sample/edit.php)

Comment: @hendr1x  yeah thats why i have suggested you second option with example :)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I wanted the system to return price/edit.php in that case, not just edit.php